# "Человек должен встречаться и уметь достойно общаться на самых разных социальных уровнях"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Запись передачи 2006 года:

> ...Да я вот сама недавно обидела одного мальчика, который позвонил,
>   когда сына не было дома. Я сказала: «Перезвоните ему на мобильный». И
>   по голосу ребёнка поняла, что он очень расстроен, потому что у него-то
>   нет мобильного. Сейчас стараюсь быть как можно более аккуратной со
>   всеми его друзьями, потому что действительно социальные слои абсолютно
>   разные. Обидеть детёныша – это просто. К тому же я считаю, что
>   **человек должен встречаться и уметь достойно общаться на самых разных социальных уровнях**. Это и есть воспитание – умение верно вести себя
>   с любым социальным слоем, от принца до детей, которые...

Comment: Если это дословная запись, то менять ничего нельзя? А какой тогда вопрос? Знаки препинания в выделенном тексте не нужны.

Comment: Это тот случай, когда дословность не важна - много человеческих речевых ошибок. Только правки должно быть по минимуму! Прошу переделать только выделенное предложение, сохранив весь его смысл!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Человек должен встречаться и уметь достойно общаться на самых разных социальных уровнях.»

Человек должен встречаться и уметь достойно общаться с представителями самых разных социальных слоёв.

Answer (score 0):

Должен встречаться – лишний текст, ничего не  добавляет к содержанию. Встречаться – это и есть общаться. *Социальный* – повторяется, надо убрать повтор.

К тому же я считаю, что человек **должен  достойно общаться на самых разных  уровнях.** Это и есть воспитание – **умение правильно вести себя в любой социальной группе,** от принца до детей, которые..

Comment: Мало ли с кем мы встречаемся, однако не общаемся. Речь об общении 7--9-летних детей из разных социальных слоёв.